# encrypt the Password in jQuery and decrypt in Apex class

Tags: visualforce, controller, jquery, encryption, cookies

I'm creating the custom login page for customer community. Login page has functionality like, `Save Username Password, Remember me.`

When I check the `Save Username Password` while login, then  at the time of next login, `Username` and `password` field are auto-populate. This implemented by using jQuery and cookies.

When I click remember me then it will skip the login page while next login. this implemented by calling `action` in `<apex:page>` which called the controller method while VF page load. controller method check cookies available and login.

I'm storing cookies in jQuery and for remember me functionality login, I'm getting that cookies(Username, Password) in apex class.

Presently In cookies, password is not in encrypt form. Now I've store the password in encrypt form. 
How to encrypt the password in jQuery and decrypt the password in apex class.

Calling action in page like :

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="demo2Controller" action="{!directlogin}" showheader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
```

script of Vf Page:

```
function submitbtn(){
      var username = $("[id$='username']").val(); 
      var password = $("[id$='password']").val(); 
      if($("[id$='UserPass']").is(":checked")){
            $.cookie('apex__username', username, { expires: 14 });
            $.cookie('apex__password', password, { expires: 14 });
            $.cookie('apex__remember', true, { expires: 14 });
        }
        else  if($("[id$='directlogin']").is(":checked"))
        { 

            $.cookie('apex__username', username, { expires: 14 });
            $.cookie('apex__password', password, { expires: 14 });
            $.cookie('apex__directlogin', true, { expires: 14 });
        }
      console.log($.cookie("apex__password"));
      console.log(CryptoJS.MD5(password));
     //here we have to encrypt the password. 
      $.cookie('apex__encryptpassword', CryptoJS.MD5(password), { expires: 14 });

     controllerMethod();
}
```

controller part:

```
public PageReference directlogin(){
Cookie getPass = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('encryptpassword');
          password =  getPass.getValue();
//here we have to decrypt the password. 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s probably not the answer you want to hear but this approach sounds everything but safe to be honest. In order to encrypt it you will need a secret. You would need to store this key in sf and then expose it to jquery (NOT SAFE). I would recommend using a password browser extension like LastPass if needed but would never store the password on the client side.

Also, I have never seen the option on any portal/website that allows me to store the password.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) to encrypt your data . And the MD5 enccryption format so when I google it I found

> MD5 means a 128-bit encryption algorithm, generating a 32-character
>   hexadecimal hash, whatever the captcha. This algorithm is not
>   reversible, ie it is normally impossible to find the original word
>   from the md5 hash.

So its not possible to decrypt it using this way. So you have one alternative solution here. Pass the username, password in apex using `apex:param` or any other approach then in apex you can encrypt decrypt them easily.

```
// Generate an AES key for the purpose of this sample. 
// Normally this key should be stored in a protected custom setting 
// or an encrypted field on a custom object
Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);

// Generate the data to be encrypted.
Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Test data to encrypted');
// Encrypt the data and have Salesforce.com generate the initialization vector
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, data);
// Decrypt the data - the first 16 bytes contain the initialization vector
Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, encryptedData);

// Decode the decrypted data for subsequent use
String decryptedDataString = decryptedData.toString();
```

[Using the Apex Crypto Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70160/discussion-between-tushar-sharma-and-user29314).